# How is Bean's property referenced?

Tags: jsf, managed, javabeans

I have something like that:

faces-config.xml

```
<managed-bean>
  <managed-bean-name>aBean</managed-bean-name>
  <managed-bean-class>some.pack.Bean</managed-bean-class>
  <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

I have a bean and in jsp page I have something like `value="#{aBean.someBoo}"`. But I dont have such property in bean's java file. There is no such thing as for example: `private String someBoo;` Instead there is `getSomeBoo()` method. The code works but I can't understand why. How does it know to execute `getSomeBoo()` if there is only `#{aBean.someBoo}`. Is it some convention that it omits `get`? What am I missing? I quite newbie so where I can find it explained well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code will assume your `aBean` follows the JavaBeans convention, that is a property is defined by its getter and setter. The getters and setters respectively are of the form `PropertyType get<PropertyName>()` and `void set<PropertyName>(PropertyType)`. Note the name of the property begins with a capital letter in the getter and setter methods, while the bean property's name begins with a lower case letter.

Comment: Is there any more 'conventions'? Where I can learn about this?

Comment: You'd find all about those in the API specification on java.sun.com ... For what concerns JSF beans, I think that's quite all you need to know.